# Wordpress woocommerce_get_price flter is not working?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

i am used Events Plugin. the plugin link is [Events Plugin Link](http://wordpress.org/plugins/the-events-calendar/screenshots/).

This Plugin is integrated with the Woocommerce Tickets plugin.

not i want to filter price of the Tickets i used this hook for change price.

```
add_action('woocommerce_get_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);
function change_price_regular_member($price, $product){
   return '$150';
}
```

This is working fine.

But this filter change value in admin side and front side.

i want to cahnge price only front side not admin side.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please return value to checking the is admin to return origin price.
or front end return your price.

```
if ( ! is_admin() ) {
     return '$150';
} else {
     return $price;
}
```

i hope this is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can also do like this

```
if(!is_admin()){
   add_action('woocommerce_get_price','change_price_regular_member', 10, 2);}
```

Thats it. it will work.